# StringRequest response empty for no apparent reason

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

With my original PHP web service `public void onResponse(String response)` the `response` contains the following response:

> {"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!"}

With my updated PHP web service the `response` is empty, non existent.

When running the PHP web service in my browser I get the following JSON object:

> {"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!","like_id":"428"}

This is great, but I want `response` look the same in the app.

So: What is the cause, and how do I make the JSON object appear in `response`?

**Java code**

```
public void writeLikedPos(LatLng location) {
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        try {
            latitude = location.latitude; //nullpointer
            longitude = location.longitude;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Noe gikk galt!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        final String latitudeStr = String.valueOf(latitude);
        final String longitudeStr = String.valueOf(longitude);

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                System.out.println("String response: " +response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("latitude", latitudeStr);
                params.put("longitude", longitudeStr);

                return params;
            }
        };
        VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToReqQueue(postRequest);
    }
}
```

**New web service PHP (result not showing up in `response`)**

```
<?php
//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {


    //initial query
    if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO spot ( latitude, longitude, user_id ) VALUES ( :lat, :long, :uid ) ";
        //Update query
        $query_params = array(
            ':lat' => $_POST['latitude'],
            ':long' => $_POST['longitude'],
            ':uid' => $_POST['user_id']
            );

    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO spot ( latitude, longitude ) VALUES ( :lat, :long ) ";
        //Update query
        $query_params = array(
            ':lat' => $_POST['latitude'],
            ':long' => $_POST['longitude']
            );
    }
    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add lat/long-pair!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $latt = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longg = $_POST['longitude'];

    $getId = "SELECT id FROM spot WHERE latitude=$latt AND longitude=$longg LIMIT 1";
    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt2   = $db->prepare($getId);
        $result2 = $stmt2->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't retrieve like_id!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $row = $stmt2->fetchAll();
    if($row) {

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Spot Successfully Added!";
    $response["like_id"] = $row[0]['id'];
    echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    ?>
    <h1>Registrer GPS-koordinater</h1>
    <form action="idtest.php" method="post">
        Latitude:<br />
        <input type="text" name="latitude" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Longitude:<br />
        <input type="text" name="longitude" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Google ID:<br />
        <input type="text" name="user_id" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Opprett kolonne i 'spot'" />
    </form>
    <?php
}

?>
```

**Original web service PHP:**

```
<?php
// TODO: Lag en sjekk for at lat/long faktisk er lat/long-verdier.

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //initial query
    if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO spot ( latitude, longitude, user_id ) VALUES ( :lat, :long, :uid ) ";
        //Update query
        $query_params = array(
            ':lat' => $_POST['latitude'],
            ':long' => $_POST['longitude'],
            ':uid' => $_POST['user_id']
            );

    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO spot ( latitude, longitude ) VALUES ( :lat, :long ) ";
        //Update query
        $query_params = array(
            ':lat' => $_POST['latitude'],
            ':long' => $_POST['longitude']
            );
    }
    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add lat/long-pair!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Spot Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    ?>
    <h1>Registrer GPS-koordinater</h1>
    <form action="addspottest.php" method="post">
        Latitude:<br />
        <input type="text" name="latitude" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Longitude:<br />
        <input type="text" name="longitude" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Google ID:<br />
        <input type="text" name="user_id" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Opprett kolonne i 'spot'" />
    </form>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: in the `$getId` query try changing the `WHERE` clause to `latitude=:lat AND longitude=:lng`

Comment: Your new web service PHP is open to sql injection attacks. Use prepared statements in the `SELECT` just like you do in the `INSERT`. This is aside from your problem

Comment: @ColinGillespie when I echo `$getId` your solution gives 
`SELECT id FROM spot WHERE latitude=:lat AND longitude=:lng LIMIT 1` (which won't work..)

Comment: Since you're not getting an answer with the new web service, obviously `if ($row) {` is failing.

Comment: @user1736049 sorry :lng should be `:long`

Comment: @JonathanM thank you, I'll look into SQL injections.. I am getting an answer when using my web browser. But not when I am using the Android app.

Comment: @user1736049 Also maybe declare `$query_params` straight away after the `if (!empty($_POST)) {` part. I'm a php noob so not sure if that actually changes things.

Comment: @ColinGillespie then there would be no `id` `(like_id)` as the `INSERT` statement has not yet been executed.

Comment: @user1736049 I believe the problem may be coming from the `getId` query. You create the query by injecting the post parameters directly into it (bad sqlinjection, etc) but then you also bind paramters to it using `$stmt2->execute($query_params);` This *could* cause it to generate an error or fetch no data at all.

Comment: @ColinGillespie but it's not making any error when I run it in my browser. It looks like `{"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!","like_id":"654"}` which is great. But this doesn't happen in Volley/Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am dumbfounded as to why the script displays a correct JSON-object in the web browser, but nothing in the Volley `onResponse`.

A better way to achieve what is being done in `New web service PHP` is to do only one query, the one in the `Original web service PHP`, and use

[`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) **OR**
[`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Depending on which method you use for MySql connection.